# How to display the date example format " 15-Apr-2012 10.12 AM"  exactly using this javascript new Date() format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, format

I need to display the date format like this  15-Apr-2012 10.12 AM.I tried to use time=new Date() using javascript.But i couldnt get the correct date format .it shows the GMT global timing.I need to display the time format.please anyone can know?

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/). If you're planning to do more stuff with dates than just formatting it, I would strongly suggest it. Definitely makes things easier with manipulation and displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is use a library: try [Moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/), it is the real deal.